# IIS error log makes no sense

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

I'm pretty new to doing server side programming, and I just enabled error tracing in IIS 8.5 to try and find the cause of a 500 error I keep getting.

This is the error file I got...

[image]

It says the problem was line 132, which says the HTTPstatus is 500, which is what I'm getting, but the ErrorCode is "The operation completed successfully."

Has anyone seen this before or have any idea what it means?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Can you post the code that's causing this ?

Comment: It makes sense if you dig further into more examples. When the handler decides to set status code to 500 for its own reasons, why shouldn't IIS mark the operation as success?

Comment: It makes sense if you dig further into more examples. When the handler decides to set status code to 500 for its own reasons, why shouldn't IIS mark the operation as success?

Comment: What do you mean by "the handler?" I don't understand how there can be a 500 server error and IIS say success at the same time.